# issue with autocomplete searchbox in laravel and jquery

Tags: html, jquery, laravel

I am making autocomplete searchbox with laravel and jquery but it is not working and giving me error like both times at `$( "#keyword" ).autocomplete({` and `response( data );`

I don't know why this is happens and also it is not creating response drop down

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined

var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#keyword").keypress(function(){
        $( "#keyword" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{route('translations.get_translation_data')}}",
                type: 'post',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
                    search: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( data );
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#keyword').val(ui.item.en_text); // display the selected text
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-siFczlgw4jULnUICcdm9gjQPZkw/YPDqhQ9+nAOScE4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raty/2.9.0/jquery.raty.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-autocomplete/1.0.7/jquery.auto-complete.css" rel="Stylesheet"></link>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" placeholder="Quick Search" value=""/>


Route::post('/translations/get_translation_data', 'Admin\TranslationController@get_translation_data')->name('translations.get_translation_data');
function get_translation_data(Translation $translation,Request $request){
    $search = $request->search;

    $language = Session::get('language');
    $lang_id = $language['id'];//$request->input('lang');
    $translations = $translation;
    if($lang_id!=''){
        $translations = $translations->with('language')->where("language_id",$lang_id);
    }

    $en_translations = $translation->where("language_id",1)->get();
    if(!empty($search)){
        $en_translations = $translation->orderby('en_text','asc')->select('en_text')->where('en_text', 'like', '%' .$search . '%')->get();
    }else{
        $en_translations = $translation->orderby('en_text','asc')->select('en_text')->get();
    }
    return $en_translations;
    //it is giving result like 
    //[{"en_text":"Abc"},{"en_text":"Allot"}]
}
```

can anybody help me in this?

Comment: Current snippent giving end of input error due to " }); " missing above the end of script,  also i did POC your code. working fine with JSON output  " {en_text: "Allot"}  " like this. make sure you get right response at ajax side

Comment: @Kul thank you for your responce and I have receive correct response like `[{"en_text":"abc"},{"en_text":"Airport Transfer"}]`

Comment: @Kul anything else you get in this?

Comment: tried with your response, working fine with your snippet code

Comment: @Kul but in my case it is not working

Comment: importing any other js inside page?

Comment: @Kul actually I am working on existing project so that there are so many js already use in that

Comment: @Kul like ` <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script> ` and all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223262/discussion-between-kul-and-mohini).